# Ajax call on jsp

Tags: ajax

I am working on Ajax call in which I need to display name based on id from database as soon as I click on a button, the name is getting displayed on the console but not showing in my form. So can anybody tell me how to write the function accordingly. Please help.

Comment: Please add your code, nobody can guess what you have done.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please read [ask] and provide [mcve] of the problem you are facing.